# Check if a database is running or not using Java

Tags: java, oracle, triggers, polling

I would like to find out if my database is running or not from my java code. I am not sure what approach will work best. The most obvious one is to have a thread that periodically polls the database. Another approach would be to use Triggers. I am not well versed in triggers, but i know that you can fire the trigger for updates, inserts and deletes. But, is it possible to fire the trigger when the database is down? It makes no sense to me trigger would work when the database is down.

PS: The database we are using right now is oracle, but I believe the same solution can be applied to any database

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers are typically server-side constructs; so to "fire a trigger" you would need to be able to connect to the DB in the first place, which would require it to be up, which doesn't help.

What is your motivation for "checking if the server is up"? Does it crash that often, or are you trying to be extra-careful before executing a database call that the DB has not crashed or your network connection lost?

If it is the second reason, assuming you are using the Java Oracle Driver, you'll just get an exception from the failed call.

Code your calls to catch those exceptions and re-attempt the connection for retrying the call. This way you don't need to poll the database; you just respond to the (infrequent) event when the connection is dead.

If you try 5 or so times to reconnect and cannot, then you could notify the caller that the database is dead and send an email to your admin or something.

There are any number of strategies here, but the point being that if you are trying to ensure calls execute, just wait for the java driver to fail and tell you instead of polling the DB server on a separate thread. No need for that.

Comment: I am actually creating a dashboard application that lets people view the status of each server. So, i need to know in real time if the database is down or not. If the database is down, i immediately need to update the status in the dashboard application.

Comment: Oh ok; then yes just poll it when the dashboard is up or write a simple polling mechanism server-side that attempts a very simple operation on the DB like 'SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1' or some such nonsense that should execute immediately and return. Catch any exceptions from the driver, update the dashboard and let it know the server is down.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a status dashboard application, I would suggest periodically (every minute? every 10 seconds?) check every database server you are monitoring. If you cannot ping the device either using ICMP ping or by attempting to open a connection to a port, this should be a high level alarm indicating either complete hardware failure or a network breakdown. If you can ping, try connecting to the database port. If you cannot, it indicates some software failure.

If this works, try running a simple query. If this throws an exception, this is some other software error. If it works, but slower than some preset threshold, it might be not error per se, but an indication that the server is "under water". You might want to light a yellow color on your dashboard.

You can also try monitoring database CPU load and overall CPU load, amount of swap file used, etc. to gauge the state of your server.